# Refer to Swift built-in class when I have defined my own class of the same name

Tags: ios, swift

I got a my own class:

```
 class Set{...}
```

And I use this "Set" as my basic dataStructure. Today I moved to the UI Part.

I try to let the textField `resignFirstRespond`, so I override the following function:

`override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`

Do you see a "Set" with generic type here ?? Then here comes the problem -> the complier tells me that the class "Set" is not with any generic type. So I aware that this **Set** here indicates my own **Set** class.

About the possible solution, I have tried :
input a "S" and use "ESC" to call code recommender, I clicked the right class. But, workless it still indicates the self-design class.

So could anyone tell me how to deal with this! Thank you!

b.t.w. I want to change my class' name too, but it got too many relative points. I just can't believe that XCode cannot  differ the classes with same name!

Comment: @WarrenBurton there is NO any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

> Swift’s access control model is based on the concept of modules and
>   source files.
>
> A module is a single unit of code distribution—a framework or
>   application that is built and shipped as a single unit and that can be
>   imported by another module with Swift’s import keyword.
>
> Each build target (such as an app bundle or framework) in Xcode is
>   treated as a separate module in Swift. If you group together aspects
>   of your app’s code as a stand-alone framework—perhaps to encapsulate
>   and reuse that code across multiple applications—then everything you
>   define within that framework will be part of a separate module when it
>   is imported and used within an app, or when it is used within another
>   framework.
>
> A source file is a single Swift source code file within a module (in
>   effect, a single file within an app or framework). Although it is
>   common to define individual types in separate source files, a single
>   source file can contain definitions for multiple types, functions, and
>   so on.

Then, you can distinguish between two classes with the same name, using a `import` keyword or `MyModule.MyClass`. If you look in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/), you will notify that `Set` is in Module `Swift`

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Swift.Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Swift.Set<UITouch>`. This compiles in a playground:

```
import UIKit

class Set { }

class MyView : UIView {

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Swift.Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

}
```

But pragmatically it would be better to rename your class.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If Xcode is showing an error, edit your question to include the complete error message, and the code that is producing the error message.

Comment: how can you failt to import UIKit?:p